# What's the difference between these 2 declarations?

Tags: c, types, function-pointers

Here's a simple and delicate question. Could someone explain the difference between a and b?

```
void (*a)(int x, int y)
void (*b(int x, int y))(int)
```

This question arise from the following Linux function declaration:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

### Solution

The following program makes a good demo.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ouch(int sig)
{
   printf("OUCH! - I got signal %d\n", sig);
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
}


void (*g())(int) // just like the b
{
   return ouch;
}

int main()
{

   void (*f)(int); // just like the a
   f=g();
   signal(SIGINT, f);

   while(1)
   {
      printf("Hello, world!\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The designers of C chose to name their types in a way that the use case of the type matches, as closely as possible, the way in which you use that type to get a value.  So, for example, when you have a declaration like

```
int a;
```

You can just say `a` to get an `int`.  If you have a type like

```
int *a;
```

Then you have to dereference `a` by writing `*a` to get an `int`.

You can use similar, albeit more complex, logic to decode the types you posted.  Let's start with

```
void (*a)(int x, int y)
```

This says that if you dereference `a` (by writing `*a`), then what you're left with is something that looks like

```
void (int x, int y)
```

Which is a function taking in two `int`s and returns `void`.  In other words, you can think of `a` as a pointer to a function; once dereferenced, you get back the function.

Now for this beast:

```
void (*b(int x, int y))(int)
```

This one's trickier.  The idea is as follows.  If you take `b` and pass in two arguments into it, then you get back something that looks like this:

```
void (*)(int)
```

Which is a pointer to a function taking in an `int` and returning `void`.  In other words, `b` is a function that takes two arguments, then returns a function pointer that takes one argument and returns `void`.

It's somewhat tricky to decode these types, so often you don't seem them written this way and instead use `typedef` to simplify things.  For example, this typedef:

```
typedef void (*FunctionTakingTwoInts)(int, int);
```

Says that you can use `FunctionTakingTwoInts` to define a function pointer that points at a function that takes in two `int`s and returns `void`.  From here, the declaration of `a` simplifies down to

```
FunctionTakingTwoInts a;
```

Similarly, in the case of `b`, let's define the type

```
typedef void (*FunctionTakingOneInt)(int);
```

Now, we can rewrite `b` as

```
FunctionTakingOneInt b(int x, int y);
```

From which, I think, it's much clearer what the type actually means.

Hope this helps!

Comment: God, your answer is such a master piece!

Answer (score 3):

Short version: `a` declares a pointer to a function. `b` declares a function that returns a pointer to a function.

Longer version: You know the following pattern to declare a pointer to a function

```
void (*f)(int x, int y)
```

Now, take the "f", and modify it. For example, make it an array

```
void (*f[3])(int x, int y)
```

Now, instead of having a pointer to a function, you have an array of pointer to functions. Now if you instead modify it to be a function rather than an array, you have transformed the first declaration to the second declaration

```
void (*f(void))(int x, int y)
```

You have modified it to be a function that returns a pointer to a function. Instead of having no parameter like in this case, your declaration has two parameters. One of which is an `int` and the other of which is another pointer to function.

It's easier to use typedefs than to combine the C declarators for doing this though.

```
// your example
typedef void signal_fn(int);
signal_fn *signal(int sig, signal_fn *func);

// my example above
typedef void f_fn(int x, int y);
f_fn *f(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(*a)` with foo:

```
void foo(int x, int y);
```

`a` is a pointer to a function like that.

Likewise, replace `(*b(int x, int y))` with foo:

```
void foo(int);
```

`b(int x, int y)` returns a pointer to a function like that.

Answer (score 0):

http://cdecl.org/ can be a good help for declarations like this. Unfortunately, it doesn't handle named function parameters, so those have to be removed. Feeding in

> void (*signal(int , void (*)(int)))(int)

gives:

> declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void